# How get Netbeans 7.2 to use 32 Bit JVM

Tags: jenkins, 64-bit, netbeans-7, 32-bit

So I am using Netbeans to develop a Jenkins Groovy Post Build Script.

Jenkins runs in 32 bit mode (Production cannot touch), Netbeans wants to run in 64 bit mode.

I can get EITHER environment to work, the problem is that I need to keep switching my PATH variable so the right version of a DLL is on the path, but switch is time consuming and annoying.

I am trying to figure out how to get Netbeans to either run in 32 bit mode or to change the PATH variable in Netbeans to use the 64 Bit DLL (something Visual Studio supports).

So far, nothing I've done has convinced Netbeans to use 32 mode and I see no way to change the path for the Netbeans IDE.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is the IDE setup anyway related to Groovy?

Comment: Java, which gives Groovy almost as a side effect, as the two are very similar. I am hoping someone offers a better solution, but currently the best solution I have is to use the -D parameter on the JVM to put the 64 bit DLL first on the path . . . the only "bad" part to this solution is that it won't honor %PATH%, so it looks like I will have to copy/paste the current PATH into the -D switch as well . . . ugly and won't self update . . . but otherwise workable.

Answer (score 1):

So I never did get -D to work properly.  The values provided there just didn't seem to be reflected in the environment like I would have thought.

My eventual solution was to create a small *.BAT file that doctors the PATH before starting Netbeans.  I would LOVE for someone to offer a better solution.

```
SET PATH=%PATH:enu\auth\x86=enu\auth\x64%
cd /d "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2"
start "NetBeans with PATH Override" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2\bin\netbeans64.exe" --console suppress
```